# What is the song in Hunter x Hunter when someone is about to power up?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

In episode 101 Killua explains to the chimera ants how he was able to catch the dart fish. This song can be heard multiple times during the series. the sound begins exactly at 17:52 http://www.crunchyroll.com/hunter-x-hunter/episode-101-ikalgo-x-and-x-lighting-646045

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sone name is Mystic land..
[check the youtube video of this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZpHlkIehqE)

.. And yeah you are right.. this music is used many times.. first time it is used when killua fights with Zushi